# Convert sql ce tables to .xls or .xlsx format

Tags: c#, excel, sql-server-ce

I have a c# windows application that makes use of a database in SQL Compact Edition 3.5 for data manipulation. I would like to convert each table in the database to an excel file. I realise that I could simply read cell by cell and export to excel, However, I have a lot of tables (upwards of 100) and this could take a long time. Is there any method to convert the tables in the SQL CE database file into Excel spreadsheets in a quicker manner.

My users wanted the data in excel because they wanted access to raw, unmanipulated data for reference purpose. Also, they are quite comfortable with excel.

Is there any simple technique to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Use ClosedXML it's open source

```
using System.Data;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable("test");
        table.Columns.Add();
        table.Columns.Add();
        table.Rows.Add("1", "2");
        table.Rows.Add("3", "4");
        ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook workbook = new ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook();
        workbook.Worksheets.Add(table);
        workbook.SaveAs("D:\\test.xlsx");
    }
}
```